# Wher is stored admin username and password inside WSO2 Prodcuts?

Tags: configuration, wso2, apim

I had face strange behavior for ${admin.username} and ${admin.password} inside APIM nodes. I need to know where this information are stored.
 
       People tell me that is an appointment for user-mgt.xml inside `<AdminUser> <UserName> and <Password>` tags. Other said that is stored inside registry.

Anyone knows exactly where this information is stored?

Regards , 
Marcello.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking about the configuration, the answer is user-mgt.xml file.

Or if you're asking about where the user credentials are store, the answer is they are stored in UM_USER table in UM_DB (or SHARED_DB in 3.x versions) if you're using the default JDBC userstore.

[image]

Comment: Hi Bee. Thanks for the answer. I asking about the ${admin.username} and ${admin.passwoard} that are used inside config file (api-manager.xml). The problem is because even after update the user-mgt.xml, The communication between publisher and gateways nodes respond with "invalid credentials".

Comment: That should work. What's the APIM version? And if you try to use the same credentials to login to some portal, does that work?

Comment: I change the super user for ADMWSO2 and config the password to myp@ssword123. First i had do it in Identity Server Console (I am using IS as KM). Following, I change the user-mgt.xml admin and password tags. I the password I use the CDATA because of '@' in password. The Invalid Credential still happen. Only work If the password and user is hard-coded inside api-manager.xml for each config (Gateway, Authenticator and etc.)